# Wordpress Plugin is Downloaded More when the time of updation why?

Tags: wordpress

I wondering because when i fix some bugs in my existing wordpress plugins and uploaded into the wordpress repository, that time i review the statistics of download is slightly increase. In Before itself it is in wordpress repository Why the Download Count is not increase(Not Thus Much)? How the People Know this ? (I am not sure is should happen through the upgrade notification of those plugins in admin side or else any other notification?) .

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Increases by how many?

Comment: For Example For a Day Its Not Exceed 15+ But When Time of Updation is 35+ like that

Comment: They know becaue they get automatic update notices in their admin panel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user know this because they get an automatic Upgrade notice [Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Updates_Screen#Dashboard_.E2.86.92_Updates) in their dashboard .

Many users just (Wrongly IMHO ) update everything when they see a notice . 
Most likely this is the reason .

Also, when you update a plugin it appears in the plugin repository (and some dashboard widgets)  as : *Recently Updated* . those links attract some people that download the plugin just to see what it is .

Another thing is the wordpress Beta testers and quality testers that are downloading the plugin to see there is no malware and that you comply with the *repository terms* .

Add all those up together , and you got a "slight" increase like you described .